# org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.ArchetypeGenerationFailure

Tags: xml, maven, xsd, maven-archetype

I was trying to create a project using an archetype but I got 'ArchetypeGenerationFailure' .

This is happening beacuse of a xml file specifically with some charters in the element of that file.

The below code is from that xml file . if I remove '**:+:**' and '**:-**'  from the value tag then it is working .

I tried using '\' in front of this charters still its not working. Any thoughts ?. Thanks

```
<ResourceProps> 
   <Tag>process.path</Tag>  
   <Value>/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/java/default/bin:/usr/java/default/jre/bin${PATH:+:}${PATH:-}</Value> 
</ResourceProps>
```

**Error message**

org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.ArchetypeGenerationFailure: Error merging velocity templates: Encountered **":+:}"** at line 30, column 86

**I tried using the UTF-8 versions of the chars**

- -> +
- -> -

But got same kind of error

Unable to create project from archetype
org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.ArchetypeGenerationFailure: Error merging velocity templates: Encountered ":&" at line 30, column 86 of archetype-resources
Was expecting one of:
    "}" ...
     ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the UTF-8 versions of the chars?

```
+ -> &#43;
- -> &#45;
```

Comment: I tried using this before but I got this error                   Unable to create project from archetype
org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.ArchetypeGenerationFailure: Error merging velocity templates: Encountered ":&" at line 30, column 86 of archetype-resources
Was expecting one of:
    "}" ...
    <DOT> ...